# Are HIV positive couples in China denied assisted reproduction methods?

Tags: healthcare, china, human-reproduction, hiv-aids

In the following article on Xinhuanet, it is claimed that HIV carriers are not allowed access to assisted reproduction in China.

> http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2019-01/21/c_137762633.htm
>
> As HIV carriers are not allowed to have assisted reproduction, He asked others to replace the volunteers to take blood tests and asked researchers to edit genes on human embryos and implant them into the females' body.

Here the head of Baihualin, a Chinese AIDS/HIV advocacy group, say pretty much the same thing:

> http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/201811/27/WS5bfd321ba310eff30328b5a5.html
>
> Couples infected with HIV cannot have babies through IVF in hospitals as it is not approved by their ethics committees, Bai said. Many families go abroad for IVF but not all families can afford it and they would face much trouble when returning with the baby back to China.

However I cannot find any concrete references about this. This seems like an important point, and I would like to know if it is actually true. The China Stigma Index (from 2009, so 11 years old and not necessarily up to date) says:

> https://www.aidsdatahub.org/sites/default/files/publication/china_stigma_index_report_2009.pdf (page 11)
>
> 28
>   respondents (1.5 percent) had been refused reproductive health services since being diagnosed HIV positive

Suggesting that (at least in 2009) a blanket ban was not in place.

Comment: "Suggesting that (at least in 2009) a blanket ban was not in place." - I don't think that's implied. The term "reproductive health services" here seems to be quite broad, and I would expect a minority of respondents to try to get IVF.

Though nevertheless, the previous quote attributes this to "ethics committees". It may just be that they tend not to approve it, rather than that there is officially a universal rule.

Comment: Your comment make sense. Right now I'm guessing that an official "ban" is not in place, rather that in practicality no hospital offers IVF for HIV positive people. However, "I'm guessing" is not really good enough, and google searches are only giving me related information in passing, nothing explicitly focused or authorative about this.